# A letter about something

Tags: word-usage

What is a right way to say about the letter, containing some information

> Did he send a letter saying when he's going to return from the city? 
>   Did he send a letter in which he says when he's going to return from the city?
>   Did he send a letter about him returning from the city?

Are these right sentences? Or is there a better way to write it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are all valid sentences.  The first one is the most colloquial (it's how I would write it).  The second one is stilted, and the third one is a little vague if the intent is to discover his intentions about when he'll return.